# Python coding trouble

Tags: python, string, recipe

For homework, I am supposed to code a recipe that takes the input of the deserts and spit out how much of the ingredients would be required. I'm still new and keep getting this error code, but could possibly be wrong altogether?

```
print("Welcome to Carmack's Bakery")

 cookies = int(input('How many dozen cookies? ==> ') )
print(cookies)

 cakes = int(input('How many cakes? ==> ') )
print(cakes)

donuts = int(input('How many dozen donuts? ==> ') )
print(donuts)



 cake_eggs = 2
 cake_butter = .5
 cake_sugar = 1
 cake_flour = 1.5

   cookie_eggs = 2
 cookie_butter = 2.5
  cookie_sugar = 2
   cookie_flour = 8


 donuts_eggs = 3
  donuts_butter = .25
  donuts_sugar = .5
 donuts_flour = 5

 print('You will need to order')

  cookies_dozen = float('cookie_eggs' + 'cookie_butter' + 'cookie_sugar' + 
   'cookie_flour' * 'cookies')
    print ('cookies_dozen' ('cups of butter'))
```

this is my error code:  come up with code snippets (a line or two of code) that produce 10 different types of errors

Comment: Post code here (properly formatted). Post the error. Don't expect anyone to go off site to answer your question. Always provide an example that's good enough so they can run your code if they choose to, but never be so rude as to require it (i.e., always provide the output and errors).

Comment: @SruthiV. A close vote is worth a thousand downvotes. It helps keep the site clean without wasting your own rep.

Comment: @OP. A gist is a type of GitHub page showing a code snippet, not a screenshot of your entire desktop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is this better?

Comment: A little. What you posted is not valid python code. The indentation has to be right to avoid basic syntax errors. There is still no actual question here. You don't explain what's not working, or provide any expected inputs/outputs. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cakes = int(input('How many cakes? ==> '))
donuts = int(input('How many dozens of donuts? ==> '))
cookies = int(input('How many dozen cookies? ==> '))

cake_eggs = 2
cake_butter = .5
cake_sugar = 1
cake_flour = 1.5

cookie_eggs = 2
cookie_butter = 2.5
cookie_sugar = 2
cookie_flour = 8

donuts_eggs = 3
donuts_butter = .25
donuts_sugar = .5
donuts_flour = 5

total_butter = cake_butter*cakes + cookie_butter*cookies + donuts_butter*donuts
total_eggs = cake_eggs*cakes + cookie_eggs*cookies + donuts_eggs*donuts
total_sugar = cake_sugar*cakes + cookie_sugar*cookies + donuts_sugar*donuts
total_flour = cake_flour*cakes + cookie_flour*cookies + donuts_flour*donuts

print('You need to order : \n' + 'Eggs = ' + str(total_eggs)+'\n' + 'Butter = ' + str(total_butter) +'\n' + 'Sugar : ' + str(total_sugar) + '\n' + 'Flour = ' + str(total_flour) )
```

Here, to concatenate string with numbers, you have to convert number to string, using **str()** method.

Comment: Please don't use `str` calls and `+` string concatenation in `print` calls. Pass the items to be printed as separate args, and let `print` do the conversion & concatenation. That will make your code both cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track here.

The problem is in your second to the last line:

`cookies_dozen = float('cookie_eggs' + 'cookie_butter' + 'cookie_sugar' + 
   'cookie_flour' * 'cookies')`

Since `cookie_eggs`, `cookie_butter` etc are all variables, you cannot place them within quotes. When you place stuff in quotes, they are assumed to be string literals by the interpreter. The interpreter will hence assume what you're trying to do is add and multiply strings and then converting the result to float which cannot happen.

Change the second to the last line to and see what happens:

`cookies_dozen = float((cookie_eggs + cookie_butter + cookie_sugar + 
   cookie_flour) * cookies)`

I suggest you read about how python strings work with math operations and the correct way to work with variables and literals.

Also, please try to stick to posting guidelines to allow the wonderful people here to help you out better and quicker!

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is in the comments is absolutely right. You should always post well formatted code with all relevant screenshots and detailed errors.

A major error you might be getting could be because of improper indentation. Unlike C++ or Java, indentation and line breaks play an important role.

As no blocks are used in this code, start each line of your code from the very beginning, without any whitespace or tabs.

Also, remove the single quotes in the last two lines- from inside `float` function and `print` function.

To get correct result in second last line, code should be

```
cookies_dozen = float((cookie_eggs + cookie_butter + cookie_sugar + cookie_flour) * cookies)
print(cookies_dozen, 'cups of butter')
```